# .map() to ignore values in array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to make .map() ignore values in array. In script below values in column B and C of dstSheet are erased when running script. I want to keep it. How to modify this script?

```
function dorozliczenia() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("arkusz 1");
  const dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bjqauqiyEzUkECaxqswRmOQPYWydpSAvLf97t5ovbXQ");
  const dstSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName("arkusz 1");

  const obj = Object.fromEntries(srcSheet.getRange("A2:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([a, , c]) => [c, a]));
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("A2:D" + dstSheet.getLastRow());
  const values = dstRange.getValues().map(([, , , a]) => [obj[a] ? true : false,null ,null , a]);
  dstRange.setValues(values);
}
```

Here are the spreadsheets:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bjqauqiyEzUkECaxqswRmOQPYWydpSAvLf97t5ovbXQ/ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ZVtFJ5Ul5nUu3PLxUu_xBlfS0bbeAWRj8-ZKwKUTG8/

Comment: Use filter to ignore. Not map

Comment: Also please use `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve] without us having to load a spreadsheet. Just dummy the data

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected situation, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const values = dstRange.getValues().map(([, , , a]) => [obj[a] ? true : false,null ,null , a]);
```

#### To:

```
const values = dstRange.getValues().map(([, b, c, d]) => [obj[d] ? true : false, b, c, d]);
```

- I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to `null ,null` of `[obj[a] ? true : false,null ,null , a]`. So, the current value is used as this modification.
- Or, how about putting only the values of column "A" as follows?

  ```
    const values = dstRange.getValues().map(([, , , a]) => [obj[a] ? true : false]);
    dstRange.offset(0, 0, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the script to keep the values in columns B and C of the `dstSheet` when running the script, you can adjust the code that creates the `values` array. Currently, the script is only creating a new array with a boolean value and the value from column A for each row in the `dstSheet`, effectively erasing the values in columns B and C.

To keep the values in columns B and C, you can modify the code that creates the values array to include the existing values from those columns.